# Create a NavigationLink without back button SwiftUI

Tags: swift, navigation, swiftui

Im trying to link a button action in SomeView1() to navigate to a someView2() without having the back button at the top of the screen. Instead, I want to add another button in SomeView2() that will navigate back to SomeView1(). is this possible in SwiftUI yet?

SomeView1()

```
struct SomeView1: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                //...view's content

                NavigationLink(destination: SomeView2()) {
                    Text("go to SomeView2")
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SomeView2()

```
struct SomeView2: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                //...view's content

                NavigationLink(destination: SomeView1()) {
                    Text("go to SomeView1")
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is what it looks like:
[image]

Comment: Don't use NavigationView{} in every View.
if you skip it then it will be ok

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The right way to get what you want here is to use the `presentationMode` environment variable:

```
import SwiftUI

struct View2: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }) {
                Text("POP")
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("")
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: View2()) {
                Text("PUSH")
                    .navigationBarTitle("")
                    .navigationBarHidden(true)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what i was looking for! I wish the documentation had more info on these things

Comment: Best solution =)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you should use only one NavigationView for the whole navigation process. Now you have three NavigationViews inside each other, which produces three back buttons.

So in your case it would become something like this:

```swift
struct SomeView1InsideNavigationView: View { // This should be the first view you present
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView { // Use NavigationView only once
            SomeView1()
        }
    }
}

struct SomeView1: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack { // Do *not* use NavigationView here
            //...view's content

            NavigationLink(destination: SomeView2()) {
                Text("go to SomeView2")
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct SomeView2: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack { // Do *not* use NavigationView here
            //...view's content

            NavigationLink(destination: SomeView1()) {
                Text("go to SomeView1")
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in `SomeView2()`:

```
NavigationView {
   VStack {
            //...view's content

        NavigationLink(destination: SomeView1()) {
            Text("go to SomeView1")
        }
        Spacer()
    }
}.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
```

Comment: This does hide the back button but it still pushes the view down the screen when you navigate (as if its still making room for the back button). after navigating back and forth between the 2 views, the views end up half way down the screen

Comment: you can also try using `.navigationBarHidden(true)`

Comment: i still get the same problem. i added a picture for reference

Comment: could there be another way of doing this other than NavigationLink?

Comment: This answer seems the most sensible, particularly if there are multiple navigation links within the NavigationView for which identical behaviour is required. However, I found that what was needed was
        .navigationBarHidden(true)