# Creating a NavigationLink in SwiftUI without NavigationView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

So I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58562063/create-a-navigationlink-without-back-button-swiftui) this amazing piece of code which uses `presentationMode` environment variable to archive transition between views without NavigationView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct View2: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }) {
                Text("POP")
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("")
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: View2()) {
                Text("PUSH")
                    .navigationBarTitle("")
                    .navigationBarHidden(true)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

but when I wrap it in another View (which is what I need to do in my own app):

```
import SwiftUI

struct View2: View {
    @SwiftUI.Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }) {
                Text("POP")
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("")
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}

struct Playground: View {
    var index: Int
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: View2()) {
                Text("PUSH #\(index)")
                    .navigationBarTitle("")
                    .navigationBarHidden(true)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Playgrounds: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("List of bush buttons").font(.title)
            List(0..<5, id: \.self) { index in
                HStack {
                    Playground(index: index)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Playground_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Playgrounds()
    }
}
```

I can only see a list of "back" buttons (without their labels!):
[image]
instead of a list of "Push #1", "Push #2" etc (which should open View2 onClick event). How can I fix it?

Comment: Dismissing `presentationMode` is not a *pop* it is destroy current presentation, ie. if you navigate once it goes to root (ie. similar to pop) but if you navigate many times it goes to root again (ie. not equal to pop). It just removes current presentation, so in case of NavigationView it is any navigation.

Comment: I'm confused, could you provide some more details?

Comment: or an alternative solution maybe

Answer (score 1):

You only need one `NavigationView` instead of defining a `NavigationView` for each `NavigationLink`:

```
struct Playground: View {
    var index: Int
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: View2()) {
            Text("PUSH #\(index)")
        }
    }
}

struct Playgrounds: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("List of bush buttons").font(.title)
                List(0..<5, id: \.self) { index in
                    HStack {
                        Playground(index: index)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("")
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have been searching for hours for this.